# Update cordova-android 6 to 9, cordova-ios 5 to 6, with nodejs 8, angularjs, ionic3, cordova8

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I hope you are well!
I have a question with some plugins.
Facebook makes a change in its registration-start this October 5, that affects the app for which we maintain.
We received the app a bit old, it is made with angularjs, node 8 and ionic3, it has cordova 8.
The plugin that the app uses for the Face Registration-Login is "cordova-plugin-facebook4" which has been deprecated for some time and they have made a fork called "cordova-plugin-facebook-connect". In order to use this fork, Since it is updated so that the change made by Facebook does not affect us, it asks for some minimum requirements that are:

- cordova-android> = 9.0.0
- cordova-ios> = 6.0.0
- cordova-browser> = 3.6.0

The problem is that we use.

- cordova-android> = 6.0.0
- cordova-ios> = 5.0.0

I have been trying to update, but the truth is that developing very little time and even less in mobile, I am quite jr, someone has already passed this, or could you give me a hand? can it be updated? if so, would you also have to update node?

You cannot migrate to ionic 4,5 or 6 because it is not an option, for times.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can imagine is time to you update your code and you will have some headaches for sure. It happens some times or all the time when we needs to support old one App versions. I may tell you that it is possible to do, but I suggest you don't do it directly on the production code.
Do create a new branch or clone the code separately to start the updates.
Pay attention you will have to update to the new `AndroidX` apis and libraries to have everything working in harmony. Also remove outdated plugins and update it for the new versions also.